# Printing macro variables with printf in C

Tags: c, macros

Can you print a macro with %u?

```
#define MAX 10
printf("%u", MAX);
```

Is it legal to do this and expect to get 10?

Comment: In this case there is no problem. You can obtain the expected output. Why do you think it is illegal?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a "macro variable". Macro expansion occurs very early in the compilation process, before there is any real concept of "variables" or even types. It's a textual substitution.

Your code is exactly equivalent to

```
printf("%u", 10);
```

which will print `10`.

There is one slight complication. The constant `10` is of type `int`, while the `%u` format requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. It would make more sense to use `%d` rather than `%u`. But values corresponding signed and unsigned types (like `int` and `unsigned int`) are pretty much interchangeable as function arguments, as long as the value is within the range of both. (`printf("%u", -10)` might be problematic.)